# Resizable dynamic containment

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

Can I pass my own object pretending to be a selector as a containment to resizable?

Please note, I've read all questions about dynamic containment/refresh containment the solutions aren't good enough for me.

the idea is - JQuery UI will evaluate containment object's size & position `hopefully` by calling  containment.width(), containment .height() and containment.position(), so by providing my own implementations I can get my containment dynamic.

Here's some code, which doesn't work:

```
var fake = { width: fucnction(){ return 100; }, height: function(){ return 200; }, position: function(){ return { left:100, top:100 }}}};

element.resizable({containment: fake});
```

Wonder if it's doable that way and what am I missing?

Comment: I hope it's not just that you spelled function incorrectly (for width). Let us know if you've solved this; I'm trying to figure out similar issues.

Comment: @charlie roberts - Hi, I've fixed it in a different way by introducing 'adorner' which can be moved w.out restrictions and then on mouse up - the size gets set considering the caps. I think it's best from the usability perspective.